# How combine query, must and must_not in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The following documents should be found:

```
matches query 'my text' AND (has not field OR field with value)
```

I have tried the following:

```
GET /myIndex/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "my text"
          }
        },
        {
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "myField"
            }
          },
          "must": {
            "terms": {
              "myField": [
                "myValue"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should (but does **not**) work liek that:

1. bool combine via OR `must` and `filter` parts
2. first `must` select by query
3. filter uses bool which combines by OR `must and`must_not`

But this behaves like `must` combined with `must_not` via *AND* clause. E.g. when I removed "must" or "must_not" query works.

How change query to combine "must" with "must_not" via **OR** clause?

Elasticsearch version is `5.3.2`

Comment: Man, I tried to follow your `AND` `OR` rules but could't. Maybe [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) could help you reorder the clauses.

Answer (score 7):

You need an extra `bool filter` between the `must` and `must_not` terms.

You should also think about your *myField* field. If it is defined as text or as keyword. 
Tested with elasticsearch 5.6.1 the following query works:

```
{
  "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": [{

          "query_string": {
             "query": "this is a text content"
          }
        }],

        "filter": {
           "bool": {
              "should" : [{                
                 "bool" : {
                    "must_not": {
                      "exists": {
                         "field": "myField"
                       }
                     }
                  }
              },
              {
                "bool" : {
                  "must": {
                    "terms": {
                       "myField.keyword": ["my field exists and has a value"]
                     }
                   }
                }
              }]

         }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

On Elasticsearch 7.X, you can simply do:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"field1": {"query": "Hero"}}}
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {"terms":{"field3":["Batman"]}},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```